# VBA Macro for copy and pasting cells from duplicate cells

Tags: vba, excel, row

I have a data set as follows:

[image: Original data]

In essence I need a duplicate row (bar the project) to be deleted and for the project to be moved onto the first line and to the right of the other one.

Example of

[image: end goal format]

I have had very little experience with VBA and any help on where to start would be much appreciated.

Comment: First, on your second picture, what is the difference between the last two lines?  Everything but the project numbers are the same so how are we to know which to combine and which to not.  Second and most important, in general SO is not a code for me site.  Please show any attempts you have done with the specific problem that is happening and we will help you.

Comment: Sorry Scott, I have attempted to record my own macro and then work backwards in the developer Tab but I wasn't making any headway. There was a mistake on the last line, the date should have been different. The solution has been provided but if you want some comedy I can show you my code?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be straight-forward to follow, any questions just ask

```
Public Sub MergeProjects()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow - 1 To 2 Step -1

            If .Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = .Cells(i, "A").Value And _
                .Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = .Cells(i, "B").Value And _
                .Cells(i + 1, "C").Value = .Cells(i, "C").Value And _
                .Cells(i + 1, "D").Value = .Cells(i, "D").Value And _
                .Cells(i + 1, "E").Value = .Cells(i, "E").Value Then

                lastcol = .Cells(i, "A").End(xlToRight).Column
                .Cells(i + 1, "F").Resize(, 100).Copy .Cells(i, lastcol + 1)
                .Rows(i + 1).Delete
            End If
        Next i

        lastcol = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
        .Range("F1:G1").Value = Array("Project 1", "Project 2")
        If lastcol > 7 Then

            .Range("F1:G1").AutoFill .Range("F1").Resize(, lastcol - 5)
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bob, my attempts were based on recording a macro and then working backwards. This works perfectly - thanks again